# Вылетает программа при нажатие на кнопку печати

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Есть программа написанная на c# .Net Framework. При запуске через отладку в visual studio работает все корректно и без ошибок. Сразу как я запускаю программу без отладки, при нажатие на кнопку печать программа просто крашится и вылетает, но никаких сообщений об ошибках нет. Зашел в журнал событий и увидел что валится такая ошибка:

```
Имя сбойного приложения: TERMETService.exe, версия: 1.0.0.0, метка времени: 0xdf4afc68
Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 10.0.19041.2130, метка времени: 0x3206f737
Код исключения: 0xe0434352
Смещение ошибки: 0x0012df72
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x3d2c
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d8e2ec21c75fc2
Путь сбойного приложения: P:\TERMETService\TERMETService\bin\Release\TERMETService.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Идентификатор отчета: 474b21d7-ede5-4fd5-bae4-ee98a4b0c840
Полное имя сбойного пакета: 
Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:
```

вот участок кода который работает в режиме отладки а без режима отладки не работает. Использую библиотеку [IronSoftware](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/object-reference/api/)

```
 private void PrintBoxLabel(string gtin)
    {

        try
        {
            string input = $"{(char)0x00F1}(01)129121739283";
            GeneratedBarcode barcode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(input, BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128).ResizeTo(300, 30);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(barcode.ToWindowsBitmapBinaryData()))
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
                        printDialog.PrintVisual(img, "Распечатываем элемент Image");
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exp);
                    }
                   
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp);
        }


    }
```

Comment: То, что вы показали - это не ошибка, а отладочная информация, которая, по сути, бесполезна. Ищите лучше в логах, должна быть конкретно ошибка, со StackTrace, ее описанием, и прочим. Пока можно лишь гадать - например, у вас заданы не те пути к чему либо, либо нет прав.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293119/12888024 - говорят, что это необработанное исключение, то есть где-то нужен try-catch, а у вас его в приложении нет. Наиболее вероятно, что какие-то библиотеки отсутствуют в папке со сборкой, либо неверно задан рабочий каталог. Настройте логирование и перехват исключений.

Comment: @aepot не думаю что это из-за try-catch ибо на этой странице только одна функция - печати. А вот библиотеки да, могут, возможно, отсутствовать. Каким образом можно это проверить и случае чего добавить?

Comment: `try { код } catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }` приложение падает из-за того что вы исключения не обрабатываете, а не из-за отсутствия библиотек, необходимых для запуска. Если бы библиотек не хватало критических, оно бы в принципе не запускалось. Вот оберните код печати, который падает в try-catch, пересоберите приложение и посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: @aepot это понятно да. У меня обернут этот участок кода в try-catch и с ним все хорошо. Там не может быть ошибки из-за того что там только эта функция.

Comment: Если бы код был обернут, приложение бы не упало. И почему мы вообще разговариваем о коде, который видите только вы? Покажите код, который падает.

Comment: @aepot добавил данные.

Comment: А внутри делегата код не обернут. У вас читайте метод в методе, добавьте еще try-catch внутри вызова диспетчера.

Comment: @aepot обновил. После добавления еще одного try-catch ничего не изменилось. Все так же не работает

Comment: Вы пресобрали релизную сборку? Что вывелось в консоль при падении? Это вообще консольное приложение? Что тогда такое `Dispatcher`?

Comment: Замените Console.WriteLine на Debug.WriteLine (using System.Diagnostics), у вас при попытке вывода в несуществующую консоль всё падает. Или вообще делайте MessageBox как я показал выше. Говорю вам одно, пишете другое, потом "не работает".

Comment: Окей, если закомментировать весь код вызова диспетчера, приложение перестанет падать? Проблема точно в этих 4 строчках? Выясните точно, какая из строк кода приводит к падению приложения. Не удивлюсь, если падает вообще не здесь, а совсем в другом месте.

Comment: В общем ошибка в том что надо использовать лицензию IronSoftware иначе ее нельзя использовать вне проектов VisualStudio

Comment: @AlexSuspect уууу. Так исключение то удалось поймать?

Comment: https://yapx.ru/u/UVD2a вот ошибка сама.Она ведет по ссылке https://ironpdf.com/licensing/

Comment: @aepot да удалось. Спасибо за помощь